# How do I pin certain contacts to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, lync, lync-2013, lync-2010

I am using Lync 2013.  There are certain contacts (or groups of contacts) that I talk to all the time.  How can I pin those to the taskbar, so that I can just click on the icon and type?

If it's possible in Lync 2010, I would totally downgrade for this feature.

Comment: You mean the Windows taskbar, correct? The Lync contact Window has the concept of Frequent Contacts that you can pin to but you want them down in the taskbar.

Comment: @BradPatton Yes, I want to pin a contact to the Windows Taskbar.

Comment: wanted to be sure. I've never seen that done. We just use the Freq Contacts list here. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are certain protocols such as **sip**, **im**, **tel**, **callto** (see full list [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx)) that should be registered to Lync by default. You can create normal Windows shortcuts using these to launch IM conversations, calls and so on, and of course pin the shortcuts to the Start Menu or Taskbar as required:

[image: 2]